# Elasticsearch using special characters

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm indexing pdf's into **Elasticsearch**.
When I search for content like "§ 123", than the "§" is ignored.

**What do I have to do so that "§" is also included in the search?**

Here the Indices.Create:

```java
CreateIndexResponse createIndexResponse = elasticClient.Indices.Create(sep.DefaultIndex, c => c
    .Settings(s => s
        .Analysis(a => a
            .Analyzers(ad => ad
                .Custom("windows_path_hierarchy_analyzer", ca => ca
                    .Tokenizer("windows_path_hierarchy_tokenizer")
                )
            )
            .Tokenizers(t => t
                .PathHierarchy("windows_path_hierarchy_tokenizer", ph => ph
                    .Delimiter('\\')
                )
                .NGram("ngram_tokenizer", td => td
                .MinGram(2)
                .MaxGram(20)
                .TokenChars(
                    TokenChar.Letter,
                    TokenChar.Digit,
                    TokenChar.Symbol)
                )
            )
        )
    )
    .Map<ElasticDocument>(mp => mp
        .AutoMap()
        .Properties(ps => ps
            .Text(s => s
                .Name(n => n.Path)
                .Analyzer("windows_path_hierarchy_analyzer")
            )
            .Object<Attachment>(a => a
                .Name(n => n.Attachment)
                .AutoMap()
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Here the mappings:

```json
{
  "attachments": {
    "mappings": {
      "properties": {
        "attachment": {
          "properties": {
            "author": {
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword",
                  "ignore_above": 256
                }
              }
            },
            "content": {
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword",
                  "ignore_above": 256
                }
              }
            },
            "content_length": {
              "type": "long"
            },
            "content_type": {
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword",
                  "ignore_above": 256
                }
              }
            },
            "creator_tool": {
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword",
                  "ignore_above": 256
                }
              }
            },
            "date": {
              "type": "date"
            },
            "description": {
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword",
                  "ignore_above": 256
                }
              }
            },
            "format": {
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword",
                  "ignore_above": 256
                }
              }
            },
            "keywords": {
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword",
                  "ignore_above": 256
                }
              }
            },
            "language": {
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword",
                  "ignore_above": 256
                }
              }
            },
            "metadata_date": {
              "type": "date"
            },
            "modified": {
              "type": "date"
            },
            "title": {
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword",
                  "ignore_above": 256
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "id": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "instance": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "path": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Frank, could you provide the mapping created for the index, the code is harder to read. at first glance you might be using a filter with stop word ? could it be possible ?

Comment: @Paulo I added the mapping to the initial article.

Comment: Sorry Frank I meant the settings, the mapping is great, but I wanted to get the analyzer part. Sorry for the confusion I was not clear

Comment: The ES mappings you posted are not using the analyzer you created. I'm not familiar with NEST but special characters will be removed if you use the standard tokenizer (which is being used in your example).

Comment: You are absolutely right @llermaly. By default text fields are using the standard analyzer ... which will remove the special char.

Answer (score 0):

## Tldr;

As pointed out by [@llermaly](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3112848/llermaly) in the mapping you do not seems to be using the analyser you are creating with your code.

Be default `text` fields are going to be analysed with the standard analyser.

## Solution

You will need to specify the analyser you want to be used on text fields

```json
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "title": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "windows_path_hierarchy_analyzer"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

else the [standard analyser](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html) is used.

Which is going to delete special char.

```json
POST _analyze
{
  "analyzer": "standard",
  "text": "§ 123"
}
```

gives you:

```json
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "123",
      "start_offset": 2,
      "end_offset": 5,
      "type": "<NUM>",
      "position": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

The **§** has been removed.

Comment: Isn't that what I did in Indices.Create?

.Analyzer("windows_path_hierarchy_analyzer")

Comment: You created an analyzer, you have to tell on which field it should be applied ^^

Comment: It should be the field Attachment. But how I connect the analyser with the Attachment field?